# When can sinh(x) and cosh(x) be equal?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I know that for large positive numbers cosh(x) and sinh(x) would almost be equal to $e^x/2$ as $e^{-x}/2$ would become negligible given the magnitude of x in both cases. And so for a number like 31427.7920639882, sinh(x) and cosh(x) are equal. Apart from numbers being large, are there any other conditions at which sinh and cosh would be equal?

Comment: What in the world gave you the idea that $\sinh(31427.7920639882) = \cosh(31427.7920639882)$?

Comment: Presumably both cause nasty computational overflows...

Comment: @5xum I used Maple and mpmath library of Python and both give the same results. But as someone mentioned, this might be due to computational overflows.

Comment: *When can $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ be equal?* - At infinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\cosh^2(x)=\sinh^2(x)+1$$

If they are equal, you get 
$$\cosh^2(x)=\cosh^2(x)+1$$

Comment: Yeah, and that would be a loop then. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Never. Suppose $\sinh(x)=\cosh(x)$. Then, by definition, $$\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} \implies e^{-x}=0$$
So they get close together as $x \to \infty$, but they are **never** equal.

Answer (score 2):

$sinh(x)=cosh(x)$ is equal to $e^{-x}=-e^{-x}$
which is:
$2e^{-x}=0$, hence the answer is- there are never equal.

Your given number $31427.7920639882$ is actually not good example, may be you just calculated on computer, which have only approximations not the real values.

Comment: I used Maple and mpmath library of Python to calculate. Do you think that there's a better way to do it?

Comment: When you are doing that kind of calculations on computer you should never forget that it can't be 100% precise, so you are doing some relatively small mistake for every calculation, which involves irrational number. So the better way depends on what do you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

$$cosh(x)= \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$sinh(x)= \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$sinh(x)=cosh(x) \rightarrow \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$e^x-e^{-x}= e^x+e^{-x}$$
$$e^x-e^{x}= e^{-x}+e^{-x}$$
$$0= 2e^{-x}$$
$$0= e^{-x}$$
$$ln(0_+)= -x$$
$$- \infty = -x$$
$$ \infty = x$$
These two functions only asymptotically approach each other as x$\rightarrow \infty$.